# IEObject.document permission denied error -- Any suggestions

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, excel, domdocument

I am trying to automate Internet Explorer using vba and below is my code:

```
Sub go_IE()
Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.Navigate "example.com/abc/home/" 'load web page google.com

While objIE.Busy
  DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
Wend

Set htmlDoc = objIE.Document 'htmlDoc now holds home page

Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each htmlInput In htmlColl

                    If htmlInput.Type = "submit" Then
                        htmlInput.Click     ' click on the submit button
                    End If

Next htmlInput

While objIE.Busy
  DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
Wend

Set htmlDoc = objIE.Document

Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each htmlInput In htmlColl

                    If htmlInput.Type = "submit" Then
                        htmlInput.Click     ' click on the submit button
                    End If

Next htmlInput

While objIE.Busy
  DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
Wend


objIE.Quit


End Sub
```

Once I click on the home page and navigate to the next page the below line gives me nothing:

`Set htmlDoc = objIE.Document`

It just says permission denied.

I did little research and found that it is some thing related to same origin policy. But I checked and the URL does not change after clicking on submit button in the home page.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was not giving enough time for the page to load, just added a condition to check if the page is busy and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using xmlHTTP object instead of using IE.
HTTP requests a easier, and a lot faster

Below is sample code

```
Sub xmlHttp()

    Dim URl As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim xmlHttp As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object


    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        URl = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1)

        Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        xmlHttp.Open "GET", URl, False
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        xmlHttp.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
        Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)


        str_text = Replace(link.innerHTML, "<EM>", "")
        str_text = Replace(str_text, "</EM>", "")

        Cells(i, 2) = str_text
        Cells(i, 3) = link.href
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

HTH
**Santosh**

Comment: Thanks so much santosh. I will definitely try `XmlHttp`